# Can someone explain how mypoly is used in Python with GPS coordinates?

Tags: python, gps, polygon

I understand I can define a polygon in Python using "mypoly".

```
myPoly = Polygon(p1,p2,p3,…) #list of points
```

However, what I really want to do is to find a way to use Python to work with polygons that I define with GPS coordinates.  The coordinates would show shapes similar to the following:

[multiple polygons http://www.jvanderhook.info/images/slabs/drawing_1.png](http://www.jvanderhook.info/images/slabs/drawing_1.png)

(the image came from [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/952/whats-an-efficient-way-to-visit-every-reachable-space-on-a-grid-with-unknown-ob/958#958%29) on Robotics Stack Exchange

I understand I should be able to work with a polygon once I have it defined, but this is new to me.  **How can I define one with GPS coordinates?  Do I simply replace p1, p2, p3, ... above with the GPS coordinates?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the gps coordinates to define your polygons.  However, understand that these coordinates are typically in degrees (+/- 0-90 lat, +/- 0-180 lon).

Unfortunately, these things aren't as simple as they initially seem they should be.  It might help to get comfortable with map projections, here's a good start:

http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/map%20projections/mappro.html

Then, you may be better off converting to a projection like 900913 ([google maps projection](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/A2ygEJ5eG-o)) that is  in meters and makes points easier to manage.

I tend to use **[django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#introduction)** (which uses geos/gdal/proj4 and is a bit of a pain to get everything working right) for geometry manipulation and transforms. (**[shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)** and **[pyproj](https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/)** seem like good alternatives if your not using django already)

Comment: Does it make a difference if my GPS coordinates are only tens of meters apart?  I'm not talking about a significant curvature of the earth for these polygons.  I think for my purposes, they can be treated as flat.

Comment: while the installation overhead is a bit high, if I were to do it, I'd go ahead and covert to 900913.  But it depends on what your going to do with it afterwards.  If it's only for display using the gps (decimal degrees) shouldn't be a problem.  However, if you want to do any kind of distance calculation, you'd probably be better off in another projection.